# how to split comma separated string and collect unique values in hive?

Tags: string, hive, hiveql, explode

I have one hive table with two column. Type of both column is string. One is simple client id and other is command separated string of item ids. There can be multiple row with same client id but different item id string.

I want one hive query which generate table with two column. one is client id and other is comma separated string with all unique item ids.

Data in original table:

```
Client Id       Item Ids
1               1,2,3,4
2               3,4,6,8
4               4,5,1,3
2               3,4,7,8
3               5,6,8,2
4               7,8,9,4
```

Query should generate this result

```
 Client Id       Item Ids
 1               1,2,3,4
 2               3,4,7,6,8
 4               4,5,1,3,7,8,9
 3               5,6,8,2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `explode()` and `collect_set()` to get unique set, aggregate string using `concat_ws` and group by `Client_id`:

```
hive> select Client_id, concat_ws(',',collect_set(item_id)) as item_ids
    > from test_t lateral view explode(split(item_ids,',')) a as item_id
    > group by Client_id;
```

Output:

```
OK
1       1,2,3,4
2       3,4,6,8,7
3       5,6,8,2
4       4,5,1,3,7,8,9
```